# Hibernate infinite recursive error in Many-To-One relation

Tags: xml, hibernate, many-to-one

May be I don't understand some kernel things, but hope.

First of all: I'm using dynamic-map entity mode (I know it is not an elegant approach):

```xml
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-mapping http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-mapping/hibernate-mapping-4.0.xsd">
    <class entity-name="UserInfo" schema="MDM_DATA" table="UserInfo">
        <tuplizer entity-mode="dynamic-map" class="org.hibernate.tuple.entity.DynamicMapEntityTuplizer"/>
        <id column="user_id" name="user_id" type="long">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <property column="lastName" name="lastName" type="text"/>
        <property column="firstName" name="firstName" type="text"/>
        <property name="lastrec" type="int" generated="insert">
            <column name="lastrec" default="1" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="recdateend" type="timestamp" generated="insert">
            <column name="recdateend" default="CAST('01/01/3000' as timestamp)" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="recdatebegin" type="timestamp" generated="insert">
            <column name="recdatebegin" default="current_timestamp" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="recdatenew" type="timestamp" generated="insert">
            <column name="recdatenew" default="current_timestamp" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <set lazy="false" inverse="true" cascade="all" name="UserExtraParam">
            <key column="user_id"/>
            <one-to-many class="UserExtraParam"/>
        </set>
    </class>
    <class entity-name="UserExtraParam" schema="MDM_DATA" table="UserExtraParam">
        <tuplizer entity-mode="dynamic-map" class="org.hibernate.tuple.entity.DynamicMapEntityTuplizer"/>
        <id column="user_id" name="user_id" type="long">
            <generator class="foreign">
                <param name="property">UserInfo</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <property column="param_value" name="param_value" type="text"/>
        <property column="param_key" name="param_key" type="text"/>
        <many-to-one name="UserInfo" column="user_id" lazy="proxy" insert="false" update="false" class="UserInfo" not-null="false"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And when i want to receive all data by query(something like this):

```sql
select ent from UserInfo ent
```

I get a infinite recursive error (when i suppose hibernate try to get UserExtraParam for UserInfo):

```
Hibernate: select userinfo0_.user_id as user_id1_1_, userinfo0_.lastName as lastname2_1_, userinfo0_.firstName as firstnam3_1_, userinfo0_.recdatebegin as recdateb4_1_, userinfo0_.recdateend as recdatee5_1_, userinfo0_.recdatenew as recdaten6_1_, userinfo0_.lastrec as lastrec7_1_ from "MDM_DATA".UserInfo userinfo0_
Hibernate: select userextrap0_.user_id as user_id1_0_0_, userextrap0_.user_id as user_id1_0_1_, userextrap0_.param_key as param_ke2_0_1_, userextrap0_.param_value as param_va3_0_1_ from "MDM_DATA".UserExtraParam userextrap0_ where userextrap0_.user_id=?
....
(last query repeat N-over times)
```

How i can resolve it?

Comment: Which kernel is this?

Comment: I don't understand why i get error with recursive infinite queries

Comment: Repeating your self does not make it clearer.

Comment: Which kernel are you talking about?

Comment: Try to explain my misunderstanding. "Kernel things" i mean "how hibernate build queries for many-to-one relation" with id as foreign key

Comment: Which hibernate? Is the the Java thing (as tag describes)?